# How to remove unwanted characters in a variable?

Tags: r

How should I remove unwanted characters in a variable?

The Trump Train
'f0''U'009F''U'009A''U'0082''f0''U'009F''U'0087''U'00BA''f0''U'009F''U'0087''U'00B8'

Only the words 'The Trump Train' should be displayed.

Comment: *"I remove unwanted characters in a variable"* What are the rules here? How do you define "unwanted characters"? You need to give more details and preferably give more than one string (including expected output) for testing.

Comment: The repeated pattern of `U` and hexadecimal digits suggests that it is either unicode or *at some point* was unicode text. If it is unicode, you might look into `iconv` (and many questions on SO about unicode reference its use). If it is literal text, then I think you need to be very careful about regular expressions here: matching `U` and four digits (with or without single quotes) is straight-forward, but what are the `f0` instances? How are you generating this string such that it looks like it was but is no longer unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how the rest of your variable does look like. Anyway, [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) are a mighty tool for such applications.

Suppose your variable looks like this.

```
x <- "The Trump Train 'f0''U'009F''U'009A''U'0082''f0''U'009F''U'0087''U'00BA''f0''U'009F''U'0087''U'00B8'"
```

Then use this `gsub` to remove everything starting with `'f` preceded by a blank character.

```
gsub("\\s'f.+", "", x)
# "The Trump Train"
```

Note, however, that this does not necessarily work for all cases. E.g. if the value is `"Trump's Train 'f0'...."` the result would be `"Trump"` because there is an earlier `'`, you know?

So take this as an answer or improve your example.